# reload div contents after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i know this question has been asked lot many times but not sure after seeing so many examples, i cannot figure why it is not happening..

this is my code

```
function update(tid,sid) {
    var getTID = tid;
    var getSID = sid;
    $("#flow_" + getTID + "~" + getSID).html('Loading...');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'generate.cfm?tID=' + getTID + '&sID=' + getSID,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){    
            var k = $(data).find("img");
            $("#flow_" + getTID + "~" + getSID).empty();
            $("#flow_" + getTID + "~" + getSID).append(k);
        }
    });     
}
```

here is the div code

```
<div id="flow_#tid#~#sid#" style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;float:right;height:150px;"  class="code"> 
                <img src="#request.webbaseurl#assets/codes/#code#.jpg" style="max-height: 230px;">
            </div>
```

i am missing something here, not sure what like timeout or something but after successful call, it should reload that `div`

**Update#1**

Here i had made changes which i did the following after response,to make sure i get the image, rather than image tag, i used the div id and it loads the inside img element in alert, i tested that

```
success: function(data){
            var k = $(data);
            var hiddenField = $('<div type="hidden" ></div>');
            hiddenField.append(k);
            var images = hiddenField.find('#inner');
            $("#ystack_" + getTID + "~" + getSID).hide();   
            $("#flow_" + getTID + "~" + getSID).empty();
            $("#flow_" + getTID + "~" + getSID).append(images.html());
        }
```

but it does reload the div, if i refresh the whole page, it do show me the changed contents

Comment: var k = $(data).find("img"); this will not work. what you get in response?

Comment: then what i need to do, because i am fetching a complete image from the html page i am getting

Comment: you returen image tag in response?

Comment: show your response in question pls.

Answer (score 0):

you are not able to find image object directly in response.

var k = $(data).find("img");

this will not work.store response HTML code in hidden element.and find for image tag .
HTML code

```
<div id="hiddendiv" style="display:none;"> </div>
```

JQuery ajax success

```
success: function(data){ 
       $('#hiddendiv').HTML(data);
       var obj =$('#hiddendiv').find(img);
        $("#flow_" + getTID + "~" + getSID).empty();
        $("#flow_" + getTID + "~" + getSID).append('<img src="'+obj.attr("src")+'"/>');
    }
```

Comment: no, the thing is in my success response, i am getting a complete HTML page, so i am just finding the <img> tag an returning it in the response and appending it to the div, and lastly i want to reload the div

Comment: Here you need to store your response in any hidden element .and then find IMG tag in that hidden element

Comment: but why i need to complicate things, i just need the img tag from the html and append it to the div and reload the things.

Comment: But you ate not able to use find() in response string

Comment: guide me then what i need to do, i am honestly lost now

Comment: take one hidden element in your page . say <div id="hiddendiv" style="display:none;"> </div>. then follow my answer . if possible post your response in your question..

Comment: i am able to do it somewhat, but the div does not get refreshed please see my updated answer